# How can I read the GPS sensor data more frequently?

Tags: android, gps

Even if I set requestLocationUpdates to 0 seconds and 0 meters, the GPS sensor data updates only about every second. I need the satellites SNR data more fequently; 10/s would be nice. Is there any possibility?

Comment: You can send the data as many times as you like, just send it the same data 10/s then update it when you get new info from the sensor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have direct access to the GPS chip, you can set the message interval for each message. On a smartphone you cannot set that message interval.
However for consumer GPS devices the maxmimum GPS message frequency is either 1/s or 2 messages per second.
So probably, as long as you don't use an specialized GPS chip with e.g 10/s msg frequency, 
it does not make much sense, to raise from 1/s to 2/s.

Answer (score 0):

No, the update frequency of the device is limited by the GPS hardware itself, usually to about 1hz. Android hardware seems to be mostly concerned with battery life being one reason. Also, most GPS hardware that produces an output frequency that is greater than 1hz is cheating somewhere in the background and interpolating points, which you can do in code if you want more points. This is because, in general, producing a higher output frequency means a sample of fewer points which means reduced accuracy. There are really no "easy" solutions around this problem. If you need more data and more accuracy you are looking at sensor fusions and and probably some sort of Bayesian filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You set that when you start listening to the GPS. You pass it as a parameter.

```
requestLocationUpdates(Provider, TIME_INTERVAL, DISTANCE_INTERVAL, LISTENER)
```

TIME_INTERVAL is in milliseconds.

Comment: The first sentence of the question states that even setting this to zero doesn't help.